# ReCapcha v2 от google, ошибка

Tags: php

Всем привет! Возникла такая ошибка с капчей. 
Вот код, обработчик:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$key = 'Секретный ключ введен правильно';
$query = $url.'?secret='.$key.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));
var_dump($data);

if (isset($_POST['send-message'])) {

    if (!$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) {
        exit("Заполните капчу!");
    }
}
```

Так вот, в коде есть вар дамп, вообщем он мне выдает NULL хотя если обратиться прямиком по этому url то всё заработает, подскажите, что я не правильно делаю???

Comment: я не знаю, но стоит посмотреть сначала, что возвращает file_get_contents($query), скорее всего  там не json

Comment: @splash58 Я пробовал и без json, все равно либо возвращает нул либо вообще ничего

Comment: попробуйте query вставить в строку браузера. Если получится, значит надо, как минимум брать curl. Можно еще попробовать загрузить через  file_get_contents() какой-нить сайт, возможно у вас php не понимает урл из-за настроек

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой комментарий не содержит ответ на ваш вопрос, подмечу что нужно использовать POST запрос и лучшим решением будет использовать cURL встроенный в php.

upd: ответ на ваш вопрос содержится на англоязычном SO - [curl-recaptcha-not-working-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354633/curl-recaptcha-not-working-php)

Comment: А как сделать через cURL, можете сказать?

Comment: @Stell , вот ассоциация и ваш готовый код - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354633/curl-recaptcha-not-working-php